# Creating a repeatable pdf document using Python

Tags: python, pdf, latex

I am looking to create repeatable PDFs (wedding invites) using python. I am currently using LaTeX to create the PDF as I thought that it would be easy to compile the invitations with different names from python. This is where I need some help. I have written a very simple python script (*below*) to go through a .csv files and create the names I want on the invitation. Now I want to get some code that will paste the names in the latex code and compile it using the package. I have seen that there is something called PyLaTeX but I cant seem to figure out how it works. Any help?

Python code:

```
import csv

name1 = []
name2 = []
name3 = []
name4 = []
name5 = []
name6 = []

with open('Guest List - Clean.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:

        name1 = []
        name2 = []
        name3 = []
        name4 = []
        name5 = []
        name6 = []

        name1 = row[1]
        name2 = row[2]
        name3 = row[3]
        name4 = row[4]
        name5 = row[5]
        name6 = row[6]
    
        email = row[7]

        if name2 == "":
            names = name1
        elif name3 == "":
            names = name1 + " & " + name2
        elif name4 == "":
            names = name1 + ", " + name2 + " & " + name3
        elif name5 == "":
            names = name1 + ", " + name2 + ", " + name3 + " & " + name4
        elif name6 == "":
            names = name1 + ", " + name2 + ", " + name3 + ", " + name4 + " & " + name5
        else:
            names = name1 + ", " + name2 + ", " + name3 + ", " + name4 + ", " + name5 + " & " + name6 
        
        print(names)
        print(email)
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangeish}{HTML}{de762c}
\definecolor{greyish}{HTML}{595959}

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{My Title}
\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{210mm}(0mm,70mm)
\setmainfont{QuicksandBook-Regular}
\color{orangeish}
\fontsize{54}{60}\selectfont
\centering
SAVE THE DATE
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{210mm}(0mm,110mm)
\setmainfont{QuicksandLight-Regular}
\color{greyish}
\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont
\centering
TO CELEBRATE THE WEDDING OF
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{210mm}(0mm,145mm)
\setmainfont{QuicksandLight-Regular}
\color{greyish}
\fontsize{48}{50}\selectfont
\centering
X \& Y
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{210mm}(0mm,200mm)
\setmainfont{QuicksandLight-Regular}
\color{greyish}
\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont
\centering
01.01.2000\par
EARTH\par
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{200mm}(0mm,280mm)
\setmainfont{Quicksand}
\color{greyish}
\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont
\flushright
"names" FROM PYTHON HERE\par
INVITATIONS TO FOLLOW
\end{textblock*}

%Adds the background image to the ivite
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{save_the_date_2_compressed.jpeg}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are dedicated packages to use csv files directly in tex. - no need for this whole python overhead just to merge a few strings ...

Comment: for example https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple

Comment: Well, one of the reasons I wanted to use Python is, firstly I need to create 100+ invites and secondly I want to write some code that will send the PDF's to everyone in the .csv. If I can do this in Tex then that would be perfect!